# IE 11 img lazy load, page freeze

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

To lazy load images I hold src value in my own 'data-original' attribute and after page is loaded, I copy value from 'data-original' attribute to 'src'. That causes lazy load of all images on page. However, on IE10 and IE11 when during images loading I change page on our menu, page will change only after all images will be loaded. On other browsers, loading images is interrupted and page is changed. How to tell IE10/11 to abort current loading and go to selected page?

My code which I use to copy value from 'data-original' attribute to 'src':

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.each($('.asset-image'), function () {
            var this_image = this;
            var src = $(this_image).attr('src') || '';
            if (!src.length > 0) {
                var dataOriginal = $(this_image).attr('data-original') || '';
                if (dataOriginal.length > 0) {
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.src = dataOriginal;
                    $(img).load(function () {
                        this_image.src = this.src;
                    });
                    $(img).error(function () {
                        $(this).unbind("error").attr("src","icon_no_image.png");
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You could use a sniffer, https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin

Comment: How can it help in my problem? I want to fix this code to work on IE10/11, to be able to lazy load of images.

Comment: Well including the plugin you can see if someone uses IE and do a normal load of images. For example you could use an `if` for detection of the browser. If it is IE, than don't do a lazy load. Something like `if ($.browser.msie) { // don't lazy load function }`

Comment: Yes, but I want lazy load also on IE.